# AWS role switching (EMR,EC2,ECS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, amazon-ecs

I am running a Python application on an EC2 instance but I cannot access the data from a certain bucket due to the role that I am using (changing bucket policies is not an option).

I was advised to switch from EC2 to EMR since the EMR uses EMRFS which would support the seamless witch of the roles. I was wondering how hard it would be to switch from EC2 to EMR considering that I am not using the Hadoop framework.

Also would ECS be an alternative for seamlessly switching roles?

Comment: For ECS, you need to run your python code inside docker container and you can give different IAM roles for different ECS service containers. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a Role for the EC2 Instance that has a Policy attached to it that allows access to the S3 bucket? You won't have to modify the bucket policy in that case, only the instance policy. See [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html). You know you can seamlessly change an EC2 instances role as well: [easily replace or attach an iam role to an existing ec2 instance by using the ec2 console](http://%20https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/)

Comment: Because for accessing other s3 buckets I need to use another role (and the roles and their access are created and defined by the company, therefore not to be changed)

Comment: A role can have multiple policies, so you can have all the policies needed for that EC2 instance under one role. If you can't modify the roles and policies then I'm afraid there is no way to bypass IAM to gain access to something you shouldn't have access to. Maybe you should discuss this with the company? Also FYI, EMR doesn't magically fix this issue. EMR simply launches a bunch of EC2 instances for you and manages them. You'll still need to define the roles and policies for the instances.

Comment: Well, the different roles are created in a way to have access to different buckets. Accessing this data and switching between the accounts it is not an issue through the UI or through the aws cli but becomes an issue when the job has to be run on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Hmm I see. Maybe you can create a Role for your EC2 Instances with a Policy that allows sts:AssumeRole and then create two different Roles for S3 access, each giving access to a different bucket. Your EC2 Instance can call AssumeRole on the role it needs to get temporary credentials to allow you to do whatever you want on that S3 bucket. But honestly, I think you should just update the EC2 Role with two Policies that give the EC2 Instances access to those buckets...